# Using loop for web links

Tags: r, loops

I want to download a data from the web, but the code is too long and prone to make an error. Is there any way to use loop for web links? The only value that changes is a number of weeks.

Small example from my code:

```
library(XML)

# import - week 1
data11=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=1&mid1=1&mid2=2")
data12=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=1&mid1=3&mid2=4")
data13=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=1&mid1=5&mid2=6")
data14=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=1&mid1=7&mid2=8")
data15=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=1&mid1=9&mid2=10")
data16=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=1&mid1=11&mid2=12")

data11 <- data11[[4]] 
data12 <- data12[[4]]
data13 <- data13[[4]]
data14 <- data14[[4]]
data15 <- data15[[4]]
data16 <- data16[[4]]

mlb.data1 <- rbind(data11, data12, data13, data14, data15, data16) 

# import - week 2
data11=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=2&mid1=1&mid2=2")
data12=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=2&mid1=3&mid2=4")
data13=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=2&mid1=5&mid2=6")
data14=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=2&mid1=7&mid2=8")
data15=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=2&mid1=9&mid2=10")
data16=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=2&mid1=11&mid2=12")

data11 <- data11[[4]] 
data12 <- data12[[4]]
data13 <- data13[[4]]
data14 <- data14[[4]]
data15 <- data15[[4]]
data16 <- data16[[4]]

mlb.data2 <- rbind(data11, data12, data13, data14, data15, data16) 

# import - week 3
data11=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=3&mid1=1&mid2=2")
data12=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=3&mid1=3&mid2=4")
data13=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=3&mid1=5&mid2=6")
data14=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=3&mid1=7&mid2=8")
data15=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=3&mid1=9&mid2=10")
data16=readHTMLTable(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=3&mid1=11&mid2=12")

data11 <- data11[[4]] 
data12 <- data12[[4]]
data13 <- data13[[4]]
data14 <- data14[[4]]
data15 <- data15[[4]]
data16 <- data16[[4]]

mlb.data3 <- rbind(data11, data12, data13, data14, data15, data16) 

# add number of week
mlb.data1$week      <- 1
mlb.data2$week      <- 2
mlb.data3$week      <- 3

# complete table
mlb.complet <- rbind(mlb.data1, mlb.data2, mlb.data3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, note that link is returning a list of 2 tables, you need to clean it up after `readHTMLTable` function.

```
output <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(1:2, function(week){
            do.call(rbind,
                    lapply(seq(2,12,2),function(id){
                      x <- readHTMLTable(paste0(doc = "http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1/2276/matchup?week=",week,"2&mid1=1&mid2=",id))
                      #choose which tables to keep
                      res <- x$statTable3
                      res$WEEK <- week
                      res$ID <- id
                      res
                    }))
          })
  )
```